# How do I store multiple thread function results to one array or vector

Tags: multithreading, c++11

I made a program that found prime numbers within two specified boundaries. It was pretty easy to make and it worked well. The problem was it was just too slow. To fix that I decided to use multiple threads to split up the task. 100 threads would be created if the difference in the boundaries was 100 or over. Each thread would call the function `PrimeIterator` and have the workload of the difference in boundaries divided by 100. For example: if I entered the start boundary as 100 and the end boundary as 1100, each of the 100 threads would compute 10 numbers to determine if they are primes or not.

Obviously, each of the threads will be running at the same time. I want all the determined prime numbers to be stored in one array. To do this I tried creating 100 different vectors (with a for loop) for each thread to store the numbers in so there wasn't a global array being used by all 100 threads. Hypothetically (never got it to work), after being stored they would be sorted and stored into one array/vector where they can be displayed to the user.

The problem: How do I store values from all 100 threads calling the same function PrimeIterator?

Note: The logic for dividing the workload equally to each thread is not completed and doesn't work. I don't need any help with that part.

**Code:**

```
include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
#include <thread>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

bool PrimeNumberChecker(int x);
void PrimeIterator(int x, int y);



static const int num_threads = 99;

int main()
{
    int val1, dividend, divisor, threadIterator1, threadIterator2;
    int x, y, i;
    thread t[num_threads];

    cout << "Enter Start Boundary: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "\nEnter End Boundary: ";
    cin >> y;

    val1 = (y - x) / 100;
    dividend = floor(val1);
    divisor = fmod(y-x, 100);


    if (y-x >= 100) 
    {
        thread t2(PrimeIterator, x, divisor);

        for (i = 1; i <= num_threads; i++)
        {
            threadIterator1 = dividend * i;
            threadIterator2 = dividend * (i + 1);

            t[i] = thread(PrimeIterator, threadIterator1, threadIterator2, i);
        }

        t2.join();
        for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
            t[i].join();
        }
    }



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

bool PrimeNumberChecker(int x) 
{
    int i, t;

    for (i = 2; i <= x ; i++) 
    {

        for (t = 2; t <= x; t++)
        {
            if (i*t == x)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
    return true;
}


void PrimeIterator(int startBoundary, int endBoundary)
{
    int i;

        for (i = startBoundary; i <= endBoundary; i++)
        {
            if (PrimeNumberChecker(i))
            {


            }
        }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want optimized code to find prime numbers, then find some articles on that. A search of **fast prime number algorithms** will give many results.

However, there are a few major problems with your code:

- As the code is mainly CPU bound, you will not have any performance gain if you create more threads that the number of core of your processor. If you want fast code for your CPU, you might do a few tests like with 1, 2, 4 or 8 threads and compare the performance.
- You try way too much possibilities. For example, if you want to know if 101 is prime or not, you only need to try for `i` between 2 and 10 inclusively *(square root of 101 rounded down is 10)*.
- And you can also easily skip all even numbers except 2 which is trivial to check.
- Doing a modulo instead of testing `t` should also be much faster for large numbers. Your code might be fine if you want to test number below 10 or so.

Say you are searching if 101 is prime. With your code, you will try 101 - 2 + 1 values for `i` loop and about half of that for `t` loop Thus it would make about 5000 tests.

Now say that optimize `i` loop and test only 3, 5, 7 and 9 (once you have tested that your number is odd) you already have reduce your number of tests to about 200. This is 25 times faster and it is still far from optimal.

If you were testing a number around 10000, code with these 2 optimizations would be more than 100 times faster.

Comment: Good one. You should probably mention OpenMP: much easier than threads, supported by all mayor C++ compilers.

Comment: @Phil1970 Thank you so much for these pointers! I thought that the main thread can create a lot more smaller "worker threads".